# MSE: Sum of series that iterates through indices of 2 cell arrays

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, mse

Here's the function that I want to write out in MATLAB:

[image: function]

For my `ŷ` and `y`, I am using the indices of `rm` and `m`, respectively. Here's what I have so far:

```
mse = 1/n *(symsum(((rm{i}-m{i})^2),i,1,n));
```

I am getting this error:

> Error in `pcmencdec_hw2` (line 100)
>
> ```
> mse = 1/n *(symsum(((rm{i}-m{i})^2),i,1,n));
> ```

Comment: By the way, n is the length of rm and m, which are the same (20000).

Comment: Hi user15177925, welcome to StackOverflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]

Comment: Is `rm` and `m` cell arrays storing numerical values?

Answer (score 0):

### If Cell Arrays Storing Numerical Values

The cell arrays can be converted to MATLAB matrices/double arrays if they're storing numerical values. This conversion can be done by using the `cell2mat()` function. Element-wise subtracting can be done between these two arrays to find the difference between the corresponding elements (this will result in an array of differences the same length as `rm` and `m`). Taking the square root of these differences by squaring the elements, `.^2` is the next step. The `.` indicates that the operation should be applied element-wise. Lastly, the sum is taken and multiplied by 1/N.

```
%Random test data%
rm = {rand(20000,1)};
m = {rand(20000,1)};

N = length(rm);

%Converting cell arrays to matrices/double arrays%
m = cell2mat(m);
rm = cell2mat(rm);

%Vectorized approach to calculating mean square error%
MSE = (1/N)*sum((rm - m).^2);
disp(MSE);
```